# Creating Azure Stream Analytics Job through Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I would like to create a stream analytics job using only Powershell. I know that the command to do this is: `New-AzureRMStreamAnalyticsInput`. However it requires a JSON file with job details. I found a [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/streamanalytics/stream-analytics-input) provided by Microsoft where there is a small template of such a JSON file (check *Create* paragraph). However it's not enough for me.

I want to create an input from blob storage hence my JSON looks like this:

```
{    
   "properties":{    
      "type":"stream", 
      "datasource":{    
         "type":"Microsoft.Storage/Blob",  
         "properties":{    
            "accountName":"abc",  
            "accountKey":"###",  
            "container":"appinsights",  
            "pathPattern":"test-blob_2324jklj/PageViews/{date}/{time}",
             "dateFormat":"YYYY-MM-DD",
             "timeFormat":"HH"
         }  
      }  
   }  
}
```

After saving it and passing as an argument in `New-AzureRMStreamAnalyticsInput` I receive following error: `New-AzureRMStreamAnalyticsInput : Stream analytics input name cannot be null`. I think that my JSON file is not correct.

Do you have any templates of json files containing stream analytics job details or can you just tell me how to correctly set up a job through powershell?

Comment: You are referencing the wrong PowerShell command to create a Stream Analytics *Job*.  Take a look at the documentation and sample JSON file here.  This should get you going. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/streamanalytics/stream-analytics-job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way of getting your template right is to manually create an input from Portal and then run PowerShell command `Get-AzureRmStreamAnalyticsInput` to get the JSON payload.

From your example, it seems you missed the input name. Try something like below:

```
{
  "Name": "BlobInput1",
  "Properties": {
    ... ...
  }
}
```